# Are fizzy "Effervescnt C" drinks any better than Vitamin C pills?

Tags: micronutrients, effectiveness, vitamin-c

There are a number of products on the market that are advertised as ***Effervescent C***.

They typically consist of a powder or tablet that dissolves in water to create a *fizzy drink*.

Is there any data to indicate that consuming Vitamin C in a *fizzy drink* is any better than just taking a Vitamin C pill?

Comment: Better as in more effective?

Comment: @Lucky More effective is what I was thinking of.  I'm open to other interpretations of *better* as well.  Was there anything specific you were thinking of?

Comment: No, more effective was the first thing that came to my mind, I just wanted to check. There are some cases in which fuzzy drinks should be avoided (e.g. in people at risk of osteoporosis), but that is a completely different thing, so leaving the meaning completely open would make a question to broad. But the question of effectiveness is a great one, because one has to balance the stability of vit C in a solution against the improved absorption rate. I'll have to look for some references and get back to you on that.

Answer (score 2):

Effervescent pills have the advantage that since you ingest the active compount already dissolved the absorption rate is generally faster than for normal pills. This is useful when you need the drug to kick in as soon as possible, like medicines for pain or fever. In the case of vitamin C, I see little to no reason why you would need such a fast action, so I assume that there is no benefit on taking one over the other.